# SPB Gallery made white stripes, which I don't want

Tags: css, gallery, masonry

Can anyone help me with this "simple" CSS issue? I have a site: http://dev.bajan.sk/lightbox/svetelne-pismena-block/ 
There is a gallery above the footer. Between 2nd and 3rd and also 4th and 5th image there is something like white stripe from top to bottom. I need to remove the stripe, but I'm afraid it's impossible. I tried to use width:calc( 20% + 1px ) but it doesn't work. Most probably this is inappropriate size of image, but I don't understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even you have divided screen using percentage value, you are placing images with pixel values. Then It may be occurred decimal points with screen changes. Together decimal points value create new pixel.

**For example** 

For Large screen you are moving gallery image to `left: 380px`

`.col-sm-sf-5` is with  `20%`  width and when screen dividing into 5 segment it shows `380.59px`

`.59+.59 make 1px`

**Solution**

Use **percentage value** for placing gallery images (in your script)